# MySQL Join returning ALL data from left table and whatever is found in right table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Brain bad. Something isn't clicking that I know is probably simple. I'm trying my best to avoid a subquery but it may be unavoidable.

There are 11 records in the left table [`cards_types`] and between 1 and 11 records in the right table [`users_cards`]. I need to return all records from the left table and whatever is found in the right table. The only caveat to the right table is doing some IF / ELSE statements to return 0 values if it `card_types`.`id` is not found in `users_cards`. Also, there is a foreign key constraint on `cards_types`.`id` => `users_cards`.`type_id` (if it matters).

Query

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.slug,
  t.label AS type_label,
  t.points AS point_value,
  IF (c.mtg_id IS NULL, 0, c.mtg_id) AS mtg_id,
  IF (c.label IS NULL, 0, c.label ) AS card_label,
  IF (uc.points IS NULL, 0, uc.points ) AS card_score
FROM cards_types t
JOIN users_cards uc
  ON uc.type_id = t.id
JOIN cards c
  ON c.id = uc.card_id
WHERE uc.user_id = 1
  AND uc.season_id = 1
ORDER BY t.priority ASC
```

Comment: use the `LEFT JOIN` and use `IFNULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently using an `INNER JOIN`, change it to a `LEFT JOIN`. I also moved your `WHERE` clause filters to the `JOIN` so you will return all rows from `cards_type`. If you leave the filters in the `WHERE` clause, then it will act like an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.slug,
  t.label AS type_label,
  t.points AS point_value,
  COALESCE(c.mtg_id, 0) AS mtg_id,
  COALESCE(c.label, 0) AS card_label,
  COALESCE(uc.points, 0) AS card_score
FROM cards_types t
LEFT JOIN users_cards uc
  ON uc.type_id = t.id
  AND uc.user_id = 1  -- < -- move the where filters here
  AND uc.season_id = 1
LEFT JOIN cards c
  ON c.id = uc.card_id
ORDER BY t.priority ASC
```

Comment: Argh. So sorry but I actually had a LEFT JOIN in there but must have forgotten to add it when I copied it over. That's the part that's screwing me up because I know a LEFT JOIN should solve the problem. It's not...

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest, including use of COALESCE

Comment: @JasonOakley the issue is the `WHERE` it is causing the result to be an `INNER JOIN`, move those to the join condition.  Here is a link to an article on conditions and `LEFT JOIN` -- [WHERE conditions on a LEFT JOIN](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN)

Comment: @bluefeet I've apparently gone full retard today. It worked perfectly and thank you for the COALESCE pointer as well. I wasn't aware of that function. It makes these things much simpler to read.

And thank you for the article too. You rock!

Comment: @JasonOakley you are welcome, sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes to figure something out. :)

Answer (score 0):

try with left join like that

```
 SELECT
  t.id,
  t.slug,
  t.label AS type_label,
  t.points AS point_value,
  COALESCE(c.mtg_id, 0) AS mtg_id,
  COALESCE(c.label, 0) AS card_label,
  COALESCE(uc.points, 0) AS card_score
FROM cards_types t
LEFT JOIN users_cards uc
  ON uc.type_id = t.id
  AND uc.user_id = 1
  AND uc.season_id = 1
LEFT JOIN cards c
  ON c.id = uc.card_id
ORDER BY t.priority ASC
```